# jQuery apply animation if form is hovered or input box clicked

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to apply opacity effects to a whole form when it is either hovered over or an input box is clicked while the mouse has left hover so that effect does not disappear.

At the moment I have the following html:

```
<form id="search">
    <input id="search-input" type="text" value="Search" />
    <input id="search-submit" type="submit" value="" />
</form>
```

And this jQuery:

```
$('form#search').hover(function() { 
    $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": 1}); 
},function() { 
    $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": 0.6}); 
});
```

At the moment it only works when you however over and not if the `#search-input` is clicked while the mouse is elsewhere on the screen, how can I add this final part?

This is not possible to do with CSS3 because you can't apply the opacity affect to the whole form when only an input is focused as there is no parent selector.

**Pseduo Code Final Goal**

```
$($('form#search').hover(), $('form#search input').focus()).functionOn(){
    $('form#search').stop().animate({"opacity": 1}); 
}, functionOff(){
    $('form#search').stop().animate({"opacity": 0.6}); 
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code should work pretty well in getting the job done.  This also handles for if someone mouses out while they are currently editing an input, and if you are editing an input then click into another "fadeable" div, it should then make the proper transition to the new "fadeable" div.

Only thing missing is your animations, but I think you could change up the addClass/removeClass to your animate, and you should be good to go.

This took some time, so hopefully it helps!

http://jsfiddle.net/vpz2S/

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you try to do this only in CSS3? You can do it with the :hover and :focus.

Comment: That's a good point actually, hadn't even considered that even though I always try and make as much use of CSS3 as possible, thanks.

Comment: And with CSS3 you'll be sure that people can use it without JS.

Comment: Although you don't get the animation with css if you don't use transmission and I'm not sure how widely supported that is?

Comment: I don't get your question :/. But if you want a good ressource for animation in CSS3 go here : http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/

Comment: With the above jQuery the opacity will fade in over a few seconds, with the CSS3 it will just suddenly appear unless you use `animate: opacity 2s;` which I don't think is supported by many browsers?

Comment: Yes you are right, but you have maybe only people on IE, because all others browsers support it since so many times...

Comment: It's impossible to do this with CSS because there's no parent selector to apply the opacity to the whole form and not just the :focus element